# Mostrar color en la columna de acuerdo a la cantidad de productos disponibles

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de tratar de incorporar este método en mi consulta de inventario que me muestra el total de los productos disponibles, ahora mi gran problema es que quiero tratar de darle un poco de estilo visual a la consulta mostrada, ejemplo:

```
$cantidad >= 10 mostrar la cantidad en azul.
$cantidad < 10 && $cantidad >=5  mostrar la cantidad en amarillo.
$cantidad <= 3 mostrar la cantidad en rojo.
```

pero no logro hacer que me funcione agradezco su ayuda de ante mano.

**inventario**

```
<!--  tabla inventario  -->
<table class="table">
                           <thead class="table-dark ">
                              <tr>
                                 <th scope="col">#</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Compra</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Venta</th>
                                 <th scope="col">G. Unit</th>
                                 <th scope="col">G. General</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Categorías</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                             </tr>
                           </thead>




<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
productos.id_productos,
productos.codigo_producto,
productos.producto,
productos.cantidad,
productos.precioc,
productos.preciov,
productos.id_categorias,
productos.imagen_producto,
productos.status,
categorias.id_categorias,
categorias.categorias
FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id_categorias=productos.id_categorias");
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
$i=1;
?>

<?php

while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $cantidad = '$cantidad';
       
    if ($cantidad <= 3) {
                 $colorClass = 'danger';
                }
    elseif ($cantidad < 10 && $cantidad >=5) {
                 $colorClass = 'warning';
             }
    elseif ($cantidad >= 10){
                 $colorClass = 'primary';
    }



$ganancia = $linea["preciov"] - $linea["precioc"];
$gananciag = $ganancia * $linea["cantidad"];

$status_color = array(
                      
                        'ACTIVO' => 'badge text-bg-warning',
                        'INACTIVO' => 'badge text-bg-danger'
                              );
?>

<tbody id='tabla'>
       <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $linea['id_productos']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linea['codigo_producto']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linea['producto']; ?></td>
            <td class="table-<?php echo $colorClass; ?>"><?php echo $linea['cantidad']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo number_format ($linea['precioc'], 2); ?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo number_format ($linea['preciov'], 2); ?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo $ganancia = number_format($ganancia, 2)?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo $gananciag = number_format($gananciag, 2)?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo $linea['categorias']; ?></td>
            <?php echo "<td><div class='". $status_color[$linea['status']] ."'>$linea[status]</td>";
             ?>
            <td><img src="../galerias_productos/<?= $linea['imagen_producto']?>" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width='50px' height='50px'/></td>
 
            <td>
            <a href="#modificarc_<?php echo $linea['id_productos']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" 
            data-bs-toggle="modal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M9 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V7H6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1H8v1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8h1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H9V5.5z"/>
            <path d="M.5 1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.11l.401 1.607 1.498 7.985A.5.5 0 0 0 4 12h1a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .491-.408l1.5-8A.5.5 0 0 0 14.5 3H2.89l-.405-1.621A.5.5 0 0 0 2 1H.5zm3.915 10L3.102 4h10.796l-1.313 7h-8.17zM6 14a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
            </svg>
           </a>



            <a href="#modificarp_<?php echo $linea['id_productos']; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" 
            data-bs-toggle="modal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M9 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V7H6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1H8v1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8h1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H9V5.5z"/>
            <path d="M.5 1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.11l.401 1.607 1.498 7.985A.5.5 0 0 0 4 12h1a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .491-.408l1.5-8A.5.5 0 0 0 14.5 3H2.89l-.405-1.621A.5.5 0 0 0 2 1H.5zm3.915 10L3.102 4h10.796l-1.313 7h-8.17zM6 14a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
            </svg>
           </a>


            </td>
       </tr>

<!-- actualizar stock inevntario ventana modal -->
<?php 
include 'modificar_cantidad_modal.php'; ?>
<?php 
include 'modificar_precio_modal.php'; ?>
<!-- fin actualizar stok inevntario ventana modal -->

  </tbody>
  <?php

$i++;
}
}
else
echo "<div class='center'>
<h5 class='black-text'>
¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !
</h5>
</div>";
echo "</table>";
?>
<!--  fin tabla inventario  -->
```

Comment: No veo que al `<td>` de cantidad le pongas ninguna clase. Es a esa `<td>` o a la de "status" a la que le quieres dar el color??

Comment: no es a la de cantidad

Comment: he modificado un poco el cod y ahora el error ```Warning
: Undefined array key "cantidad"```   ```FROM productos INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id_categorias=productos.id_categorias");
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
if($cantidad >= 10){ return 'text-bg-warning';
} elseif ($cantidad < 10 && $cantidad >=5) { return 'text-bg-primary';
} elseif ($cantidad <= 3) { return 'text-bg-danger';
} elseif($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
$i=1;
 ?>   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este ejemplo hace lo que tu pides. Cambia el valor de **$cantidad** y se comportará como tu lo pides, solo es de implementarlo en tu código y listo.

```
<?php

    /*
        $cantidad >= 10 mostrar la cantidad en azul.
        $cantidad < 10 && $cantidad >=5  mostrar la cantidad en amarillo.
        $cantidad <= 3 mostrar la cantidad en rojo.
    */
    $cantidad = 3;

    if ($cantidad <= 3) {
        $colorClass = 'danger';
    }
    elseif ($cantidad <= 9) {
        $colorClass = 'warning';
    }
    elseif ($cantidad >= 10){
        $colorClass = 'primary';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="h2">Stock</p>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                    <th scope="col">Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>PC Gamer</td>
                    <td class="table-<?php echo $colorClass; ?>"><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edito: En base a tu actualización debo decir que tienes un gran problema de lógica, estas asignando **$cantidad = '$cantidad';**. Eso no existe y esta mal !!!!

Por eso no te funciona, repliqué tu misma estructura y vuelvo a obtener el resultado deseado.

Pero debes asignar así: `$cantidad = $linea['cantidad'];` porque esa es la cantidad que se va a evaluar y va a cambiar el color. Otra cosa, en tu actualización vuelves a poner mal la estructura de comparación. Ponla exactamente como en mi respuesta de arriba y va a funcionar.

El único código que necesite cambiar fue la línea

```
$cantidad = $linea['cantidad'];
```

Y mi resultado fue:

[image: Resultado]

---

No olvides marcar la respuesta como **Aceptada** si solventa tu problema. :-)

Comment: hola lo puse tal cual lo pusiste, pero solo me muestra un solo color ese código php va antes de mi consulta o como quedaría adaptado en mi consulta?

Comment: Ni siquiera hiciste lo primero que puse en la respuesta para ver como se cambian los colores verdad??

Comment: si lo hice pero como te dije antes solo me muestra un color cuando lo aplico al código, pero con el ejemplo que me pusiste funciona perfectamente. https://ibb.co/XbZbv3w

Comment: El código que maneja los colores lo colocaste dentro del ciclo que imprime cada una de las líneas de tu tabla?? Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y poner el nuevo código con lo que yo te puse de ejemplo. La verdad no debería fallarte, he hecho cosas similares muchas veces.

Comment: listo, disculpa por no responder a tiempo no tenia internet

Comment: De nuevo, ahí tienes lo que quieres. Por favor analiza mejor tu código, eso es fundamental para toda tu carrera profesional. Vamos que es solo practica :-)

Comment: muchas gracias @OCHOA ahora si, gracias por tus enseñanzas