# ¿Cómo listar con colores en una tabla de acuerdo al estado de mis productos? HTML - CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, dropdown

Holaa, me gustaría listar un dropdown con un color para cada estado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente solo puedo listar con dos colores, como se puede observar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando es la siguiente:

```
<td id="status">
        <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':inventarios.status === 'OK' ? '#C8E6C9' : '#FFCDD2',
         'color': inventarios.status === 'OK' ? '#256029' : '#c63737'}">{{ inventarios.status }}</div>
      </td>
```

Pero quisiera poder asignar un color diferente por cada estado (los cuatro).

Estoy utilizando **angular** y **primeng**, traté de seguir la documentación de primeng pero no es muy clara.

Estaría agradecida si alguien pudiera ayudarme !!

Comment: No pongas el código como imagen, cámbialo por texto. Así no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola BDamaris, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos

Comment: Tal vez, te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/585061/mostrar-color-en-la-columna-de-acuerdo-a-la-cantidad-de-productos-disponibles/585254#585254) aunque sea con PHP, la lógica seria la misma, solo que en tu caso en lugar de evaluar el stock de un producto evaluarías el **status**. Y por favor, pon el código en texto tal cual lo dice el apartado [ask].

Comment: Gracias por el feedback, las tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que te retorne los colores según el `status`

```
getStyleStatus() : any{
  switch(this.inventarios.status){
    case 'OK':
      return {'background-color': '#C8E6C9', color:  '#256029' };
      
    case 'REP':
      return {'background-color': '#FFCDD2', color:  '#c63737' };
      
    case 'AVE':
      return {'background-color': 'yellow', color:  'gold' };
      
    case 'MAN':
      return {'background-color': 'blue', color:  'cyan' };
      
    default:
      return {'background-color': 'white', color:  'black' };
  }
```

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyleStatus()">{{ inventarios.status }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te conviene más manejar el dropdown como template tal como lo indica la documentación de primeng, solo que en vez de banderas serán colores.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true" placeholder="Select a Country">
    <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
        <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2" *ngIf="selectedCountry">
            <img src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/demo/flag/flag_placeholder.png" [class]="'flag flag-' + selectedCountry.code.toLowerCase()" style="width: 18px"/>
            <div>{{ selectedCountry.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
        <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2">
            <img src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/demo/flag/flag_placeholder.png" [class]="'flag flag-' + country.code.toLowerCase()" style="width: 18px"/>
            <div>{{ country.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```